# Fail to invoke JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem when I try to call  method in javascript from C#.

```
//Code C# in pageLoad
string zone="something";
string script = "LoadZone(\"" + zone+ "\");";        
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Load", script, true);

//Code javaScript
function LoadZone(res)
{
    CargarMapa();
    AgregarMarkerLoad(res); 
}
```

This code works for me I put a breakpoint in the first line of the method "LoadZone" and go fine.  But when I try to change the code to call another method in the same .js just does not work.

```
 //Code C# in pageLoad
 string zone ="something";
 string script = "watchZone2(\"" + zone+ "\");";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Load", script, true);

 //Code javaScript
 function watchZone2() 
 {
     var aaa="";
 }
```

The method  "watchZone2" is below the "LoadZone" in .js
I do not know why this code not work (the last one). any idea??

**Edit 1:**

I tried what you said @ematica:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "Javascript:LoadZone(" + zone + ");", true);
```

but directly gives me another error :

> "Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript: 'loadzone' is undefined"

I am researching this error.if you have any idea arises just let me know ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem was that in the middle was calling 2 functions in javascript and only works by calling a function per postback. To fix it integrates the 2 methods in one in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it as a JavaScript ClientScriptBlock:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "Javascript:LoadZone(" + zone + ");", true);
```